# Good Luck **in** all your endeavors' versus Good Luck **to** all your endeavors'

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, politeness, nuance

What is the difference between

'I am currently busy with family stuff so I really don't know when is a good time to catch up.

Good Luck in all your endeavors'

versus

'I am currently busy with family stuff so I really don't know when is a good time to catch up.

Good Luck to all your endeavors'?

The first one sounds pleasant. The second one sounds like a good bye.

**Does keyword 'really' have a role here?**

Comment: Both are idiomatic, though I suspect the first more popular. The second sounds less personal, as good luck is being wished to the endeavours themselves rather than to the individual. Both are quite acceptable as a way of wishing good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Telling someone "Good Luck **in** all your" sounds like you are telling the person good luck.

Telling someone "Good Luck **to** all your" sounds like you are telling the endeavors' good luck, not the person.

To make the latter correct, you could say "Good Luck **to** you **in** all your endeavors'".

Comment: I wouldn't use it, but there are over 500 000 Google hits for "good luck to your endeavors" -"bring good". The first few are all the 'wishing you ...' formula. So it's being very brave to label "Good Luck to all your ..." incorrect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is what I am thinking to. But there seems a subtle difference in context above where the person could be in fact stating a good bye forever closing all forms of communication if using 'to' instead of 'in'. 'To' here seems to encode lot more information.

Comment: @Turbo I'd use "I wish you well in all your endeavours"; the illogical use of 'to' isn't applicable / available. Possibly, as you and WS2 say, your 'second [variant] sounds less personal', distancing the speaker, discouraging further communication.

Answer (score 0):

Wishing luck to your endeavors... ? I'd rather wish **you** luck in all your endeavors. Here's why: The endeavors are yours, directly dependent upon yourself, your state of being, circumstances, etc. If I wished you luck (better circumstances in your favour), you could win or become more successful.

**Note:** A google hit may bring up all that in current usage (both right and otherwise, because cyberspace is free-for-all and not subject to any control). However, it's up to us to choose the ones which correspond to our personality and expression.

Comment: This doesn't address OP's question, which is about nuances. Usage makes both acceptable (in spite of the _to_-version looking less logical). And Ricketts has already expressed this view.

Comment: This is interesting... how did I miss the previous answer?

Answer (score 0):

The sentiments are so similar that it's really just a matter of style. Since you care about the subtleties, I think the gist of the matter is this:

[In](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=in&use1828=on) usually designates encasement by the limits by or actual presence. It means you hope or believe the endeavors somehow possesses the quality of luck that will make them successful.

[To](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=to&use1828=on) usually designates a towards relationship. You're sending sending the endeavor luck. It may also indicate that the wish is for the endeavor to have greater luck than it already had before.

Using "In" seems like it might be better to send to a somewhat proud person, as a vote of confidence that things will go as they plan. Using "To" seems like more of an active blessing.

The referenced definitions are from [Noah Webster's 1828 American Dictionary of the English Language](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/).

Comment: So there is no negative connotation to using 'to'?

Comment: In some other very rare contexts there might be but in this one, I assure you there is none. I'd be more concerned about the word "luck" because some people lack even a modicum of humility and feel that their own efforts supersede external factors but that's a different factor altogether.

Comment: ok thank you this is strange though.

Comment: What very rare contexts you are thinking? So 'to' is not a good bye here?

Comment: I have no idea why OP or anyone else here thinks that using "to" would imply a "goodbye".  I agree with those who say "to" means you are wishing luck to the endeavor rather than to the person, which is very strange.

Comment: Neither form seems to occur in written BrE.  Only the "in your endeavors" form occurs, which is the American spelling of "endeavor".   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Good+luck+in+your+endeavors%2CGood+luck+to+your+endeavors%2CGood+luck+in+your+endeavours%2CGood+luck+to+your+endeavours&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGood%20luck%20in%20your%20endeavors%3B%2Cc0  Perhaps "Good luck to" is an Indian English construction?

Comment: @Turbo "To" is sometimes used to direct opposition as in *head to head" or enmity as in "dislike to" but neither sentiment is found in this sentence and it'd be contrived to read it as such. It's usually just a benign function word, controlled by the surrounding sentence. Brian: maybe since "to endeavor" is often its own concept, those words are being read in isolation? Endeavor also seems like an infrequent target. Check with fewer qualifiers: preview.tinyurl.com/q6e5kcb Also check C.C.A.E: preview.tinyurl.com/2u7gwl2 The usual target is a person but "good luck to your trip." has an instance.